# Sticky div going outside its parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create sticky div on the left (using Bootstrap 4 beta v2) without CSS that will follow the user on scroll. I've got it mostly working, but when I scroll, the sticky div jumps out of its parent element div (a ). I'm not sure if it's an HTML issue or my JavaScript is messed up somewhere.

The last div on the left begins contained within the parent col-sm-3 as per the first pic. However, upon scroll, when it "catches" you can see that it breaks out of the col-sm-3 and is underneath the main content divs (which is a col-sm-9).

[image]

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 d-none d-md-block">
                <div class="card mt-3">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mt-3" id="catcher">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mt-3" id="sticky">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Featured
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<!--sticky on scroll javascript-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                function isScrolledTo(elem) {
                    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //num of pixels hidden above current screen
                    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
                    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top; //num of pixels above the elem
                    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
                    return ((elemTop <= docViewTop));
                }
                var catcher = $('#catcher');
                var sticky = $('#sticky');
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if (isScrolledTo(sticky)) {
                        sticky.css('position', 'fixed');
                        sticky.css('top', '0px');
                    }
                    var stopHeight = catcher.offset().top + catcher.height();
                    if (stopHeight > sticky.offset().top) {
                        sticky.css('position', 'absolute');
                        sticky.css('top', stopHeight);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle? It'd help to debug